# Prevent Xcode 9 to pause on implicit runtime warnings

Tags: xcode, xcode9

Xcode 9 keeps stopping on all my implicit runtime warnings.

I am in the process of fixing them, but having more than 1000, it is impossible to run the code without telling Xcode to stop breaking on them.

[image]

I have disabled all breakpoints but Xcode still breaks on each runtime warning.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the breakpoints by unchecking the "Pause on issue" in scheme setting.
[image: setting]

Comment: I didn't find a solution to my problem, the Main Thread Checker was disabled, I was running the unit tests.

Comment: I had encountered this also, when I use a old version 3rd party library always pauses when the app starts. Update the library fixes this issue.

Comment: Downvote! I have this checkbox unchecked and Xcode keeps stopping on errors and warnings.